# Anyone know what happened to the AutoFormat feature in CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Trying to auto format some HTML in CodeMirror V4. Found the docs on how to do it but it looks like the call `editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to)` was removed in V3...

Code for V2 is below.

Anyone know how to do it with V4 today?

From: http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html

```
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "htmlmixed"
  });
  CodeMirror.commands["selectAll"](editor);

  function getSelectedRange() {
    return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
  }

  function autoFormatSelection() {
    var range = getSelectedRange();
    editor.autoFormatRange(range.from, range.to);
  }

  function commentSelection(isComment) {
    var range = getSelectedRange();
    editor.commentRange(isComment, range.from, range.to);
  }      
</script>
```

Comment: We have also faced this problem, auto formatting add on is removed in the newer version. But the old formatting add on will still work with the new version of the codemirror. We have used codemirror.js version 3_21, with formatting.js version 3_01.

Comment: Have you tried it with the V4 codebase?

Comment: No I haven't give a try with V4. I hope it will work

Comment: It was removed in CodeMirror 4 because the developer said it was too difficult to maintain. I haven't been able to find a replacement yet.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the formatting.js file in the addons folder of codemirror 4 and reference it, the functions will work.

1. Location: addon/format/formatting.js
2. include the script file in your html
3. Call the formatting code (example at http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html)

**formatting.js**

```
(function() {

  CodeMirror.extendMode("css", {
    commentStart: "/*",
    commentEnd: "*/",
    newlineAfterToken: function(_type, content) {
      return /^[;{}]$/.test(content);
    }
  });

  CodeMirror.extendMode("javascript", {
    commentStart: "/*",
    commentEnd: "*/",
    // FIXME semicolons inside of for
    newlineAfterToken: function(_type, content, textAfter, state) {
      if (this.jsonMode) {
        return /^[\[,{]$/.test(content) || /^}/.test(textAfter);
      } else {
        if (content == ";" && state.lexical && state.lexical.type == ")") return false;
        return /^[;{}]$/.test(content) && !/^;/.test(textAfter);
      }
    }
  });

  var inlineElements = /^(a|abbr|acronym|area|base|bdo|big|br|button|caption|cite|code|col|colgroup|dd|del|dfn|em|frame|hr|iframe|img|input|ins|kbd|label|legend|link|map|object|optgroup|option|param|q|samp|script|select|small|span|strong|sub|sup|textarea|tt|var)$/;

  CodeMirror.extendMode("xml", {
    commentStart: "<!--",
    commentEnd: "-->",
    newlineAfterToken: function(type, content, textAfter, state) {
      var inline = false;
      if (this.configuration == "html")
        inline = state.context ? inlineElements.test(state.context.tagName) : false;
      return !inline && ((type == "tag" && />$/.test(content) && state.context) ||
                         /^</.test(textAfter));
    }
  });

  // Comment/uncomment the specified range
  CodeMirror.defineExtension("commentRange", function (isComment, from, to) {
    var cm = this, curMode = CodeMirror.innerMode(cm.getMode(), cm.getTokenAt(from).state).mode;
    cm.operation(function() {
      if (isComment) { // Comment range
        cm.replaceRange(curMode.commentEnd, to);
        cm.replaceRange(curMode.commentStart, from);
        if (from.line == to.line && from.ch == to.ch) // An empty comment inserted - put cursor inside
          cm.setCursor(from.line, from.ch + curMode.commentStart.length);
      } else { // Uncomment range
        var selText = cm.getRange(from, to);
        var startIndex = selText.indexOf(curMode.commentStart);
        var endIndex = selText.lastIndexOf(curMode.commentEnd);
        if (startIndex > -1 && endIndex > -1 && endIndex > startIndex) {
          // Take string till comment start
          selText = selText.substr(0, startIndex)
          // From comment start till comment end
            + selText.substring(startIndex + curMode.commentStart.length, endIndex)
          // From comment end till string end
            + selText.substr(endIndex + curMode.commentEnd.length);
        }
        cm.replaceRange(selText, from, to);
      }
    });
  });

  // Applies automatic mode-aware indentation to the specified range
  CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoIndentRange", function (from, to) {
    var cmInstance = this;
    this.operation(function () {
      for (var i = from.line; i <= to.line; i++) {
        cmInstance.indentLine(i, "smart");
      }
    });
  });

  // Applies automatic formatting to the specified range
  CodeMirror.defineExtension("autoFormatRange", function (from, to) {
    var cm = this;
    var outer = cm.getMode(), text = cm.getRange(from, to).split("\n");
    var state = CodeMirror.copyState(outer, cm.getTokenAt(from).state);
    var tabSize = cm.getOption("tabSize");

    var out = "", lines = 0, atSol = from.ch == 0;
    function newline() {
      out += "\n";
      atSol = true;
      ++lines;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
      var stream = new CodeMirror.StringStream(text[i], tabSize);
      while (!stream.eol()) {
        var inner = CodeMirror.innerMode(outer, state);
        var style = outer.token(stream, state), cur = stream.current();
        stream.start = stream.pos;
        if (!atSol || /\S/.test(cur)) {
          out += cur;
          atSol = false;
        }
        if (!atSol && inner.mode.newlineAfterToken &&
            inner.mode.newlineAfterToken(style, cur, stream.string.slice(stream.pos) || text[i+1] || "", inner.state))
          newline();
      }
      if (!stream.pos && outer.blankLine) outer.blankLine(state);
      if (!atSol && i < text.length - 1) newline();
    }

    cm.operation(function () {
      cm.replaceRange(out, from, to);
      for (var cur = from.line + 1, end = from.line + lines; cur <= end; ++cur)
        cm.indentLine(cur, "smart");
      cm.setSelection(from, cm.getCursor(false));
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: But is it superseded ? Is there a new way to do it ?

Comment: At the point where I wrote this, the functionality was removed from codemirror. I don't know if was added back

Comment: Maybe it was drop to the benefit of simple indentation. (Not confirmed, but possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any 3rd party formatting tools, like [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) (it supports CSS, HTML and JS)

1. Add custom button
2. Add onclick handler for it
3. Use `editor.getValue()` and `editor.setValue(string)` from [API](https://codemirror.net/2/doc/manual.html#api)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#code')[0], {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'text/javascript',
    theme: 'oceanic-next'
  });

  $('#format').on('click', function() {
    editorContent = editor.getValue();
    editorContent = js_beautify(editorContent, {indent_with_tabs: true});
    editor.setValue(editorContent);
    editor.refresh();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.13.5/beautify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.60.0/theme/oceanic-next.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id="format">Format</button>
<textarea id="code">var APP_ID = "APP_ID";
(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/' + APP_ID;var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);};if(document.readyState==='complete'){l();}else if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
</textarea>
```